# Exact calculations of real numbers for my frequency generator

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with calculation accuracy, I'm just learning and can't figure out the error
I have this script, it outputs this list of numbers after running

```
nums = [108, 109, 110, 111]
for div in nums:
    x = 542357098500868790
    y = 0
    while x > y:
        print(x)
        x = x // div
result
542357098500868790
5021824986119155
46498379501103
430540550936
3986486582
36911912
341776
3164
29

542357098500868790
4975753197255676
45649111901428
418799191756
3842194419
35249490
323389
2966
27
.......
```

But when I change the divisor from '//' to '/'

```
542357098500868790
4.8949196615601875e+17
4.417797528483923e+17
```

I need the result to be as accurate as possible with the remainder

```
nums = [1.108, 2.109, 3.110, 4.111]
for div in nums:
    x = 542357098500868790
    y = 0
    while x > y:
        print(x)
        x = x / div
```

I need this result

542357098500868790/1.108 = 489491966156018763.53

Comment: You can not get that level of precision with 64-bit floats.  Look into `gmpy2` or stdlib `decimal`.

Comment: For me it will be difficult